# Why do we not divide by the number of permutations for a probability density function?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, order-statistics

I'm learning about things like the joint PDF of $n$ random variables.
The typical way to do this is by multiplying the PDFs of the variables, assuming they are independent.
However, why is it the case that we don't divide by the permutations of the random variables?
i.e. we know that the event ${A\cap B}$ could have happened with $A$ first or $B$ first, so why don't we divide the resulting probability by $2$?

(I do understand that there's a constraint that the resulting joint PDF must integrate to 1, by *definition*, but that still doesn't make me comfortable with just leaving things as they are...some clarification would help. Thank you!)

i.e.
Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ is distributed independently with pdfs $f_1,...,f_n$.
The resulting joint pdf is:
$$
f(x_1,...,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} f_{i}
$$
This makes sense, as we want the integral of the joint pdf to be 1:
$$
\int_{x_1...x_n}\prod_{i=1}^{n} f_{i} = 1
$$
But, in other more elementary probability problems, we often divide by the number of permutations of an event, because we're interested in the probability of the *unordered* outcome.

Why don't we divide by the number of permutations here?
i.e.

$$
f(x_1,...,x_n) = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n} f_{i}}{n!}
$$

Of course, it doesn't integrate to 1, but I'm curious as to whether the order of events affects the meaning of the joint pdf and how it's constructed.

Comment: Clarify your question.  Show by equation what is your concern.

Comment: done. did that help?

Comment: The discrete version of this question would be "If $E$ and $F$ are independent events, why is $P(E\cap F) = P(E)P(F)$ rather that $\frac 1{2!}P(E)P(F)$?" Do you know the answer to that question? (Note that your question uses $\cup$, but I'm pretty sure you mean $\cap$.)

Comment: The probability of the intersection has nothing to do with the order of events on the list.  You could complicate matters by $f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{f(x_1)f(x_2)+f(x_2)f(x_1)}{2}$, but why?

Comment: So the time when it's appropriate to adjust for the order of events is when I'm doing things like counting the events, and dividing by the total number of events?

Comment: @tuna, I'm kind of embarrassed to say that I don't know the answer to that question...

Comment: Also, $A \cup B = B \cup A$ so the "who's first?" bit doesn't really enter into this.

Comment: Thanks all for entertaining my rather elementary question.

Comment: @Daycent: That's OK! Well, technically $P(E\cap F)=P(E)P(F)$ is the definition of independence, but the intuition is that $F$ occupies the same relative fraction of $E$ as it does of the whole sample space. That is, $\frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(E)} = \frac{P(F)}{1}$. For example, if you roll a red die and a blue die, then the probability of getting snake eyes (two 1s) is $\frac 16\cdot\frac 16$, because *out of* the $\frac 16$ of times that you roll a 1 on the red die, you'll also roll a 1 on the blue die $\frac 16$ of the time. Order doesn't really enter into it; there is no overcounting to correct.

Comment: For contrast, here's an example where we might want to correct for order: say we draw two cards from a deck and want the probability that one is red and one is black. (Note that we don't have independence here.) The probability that we get a red card and then a black card, in that order, is $\frac{26}{52}\cdot\frac{26}{51}$. But we might also draw them in the other order, so we want to *multiply* (not divide) that answer by $2!$. (If you like, we are dividing the denominator by 2; instead of $52\cdot 51$ ordered pairs, we want to consider $\frac 1{2!}\cdot 52\cdot 51$ unordered pairs.)